# how to combine output values using echo & fsck

Tags: bash, array, fsck

I am trying to make a functional script just using Partition Label, get that label, from the Label get the Device, and pass `fsck -fy` twice on each partition.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Filter partition by label : except "Inukaze", "LUBUNTU" & "72GB"
Etiqueta=($(ls -l /dev/disk/by-label | grep -v "Inukaze" | grep -v "LUBUNTU" | grep -v "72GB" | awk '{print $9}'))

# Set array list using the labels for get device
Particion=($(for i in "${Etiqueta[@]}" ; do blkid -L "$i" ; done))

# And the part i need help :
for ((i=0; i<${#Etiqueta[@]}; i++)); do echo -e "\nExaminando : ""${Etiqueta[i]} (${Particion[i]})" & fsck -fy ${Particion[@]} & fsck -fy ${Particion[@]} ; done
```

Output of `ls -l /dev/disk/by-label | grep -v "Inukaze" | grep -v "LUBUNTU" | grep -v "72GB" | awk '{print $9}'`:

```
1SlackIni
Compartido
Slack32
Slack64
Tactinu1
Tactinu1-Inicio
Tactinu1-Slack32
Tactinu1-Slack64
```

Output of « `for i in "${Etiqueta[@]}" ; do blkid -L "$i" ; done` »

```
/dev/sda1
/dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb6
/dev/sdb5
/dev/sdc1
/dev/sdc2
/dev/sdc4
/dev/sdc3
```

Output of `for ((i=0; i<${#Etiqueta[@]}; i++)); do echo -e "\nExaminando : ""${Etiqueta[i]} (${Particion[i]})" & fsck -fy ${Particion[@]} & fsck -fy ${Particion[@]} ; done`:

```
Examinando : 1SlackIni (/dev/sda1)
[2] 5199
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/sda1 está en uso.
e2fsck: No se puede continuar, se finaliza.

Paso 1: Verificando nodos-i, bloques y tamaños
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
fsck.ext3: Device or resource busy mientras se intentaba abrir /dev/sdb1
¿Sistema de ficheros montado o abierto en exclusiva por otro programa?
Paso 2: Verificando la estructura de directorios
Paso 3: Revisando la conectividad de directorios
Paso 4: Revisando las cuentas de referencia
Paso 5: Revisando el resumen de información de grupos
1SlackIni: 977/65536 ficheros (24.8% no contiguos), 114672/262144 bloques
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
fsck.ext3: Device or resource busy mientras se intentaba abrir /dev/sdb6
¿Sistema de ficheros montado o abierto en exclusiva por otro programa?
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/sdb5 está en uso.
e2fsck: No se puede continuar, se finaliza.

e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/sdc1 está en uso.
e2fsck: No se puede continuar, se finaliza.

Paso 1: Verificando nodos-i, bloques y tamaños
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/sdc2 está en uso.
e2fsck: No se puede continuar, se finaliza.

Paso 1: Verificando nodos-i, bloques y tamaños
Paso 2: Verificando la estructura de directorios
Paso 3: Revisando la conectividad de directorios
Paso 4: Revisando las cuentas de referencia
Paso 5: Revisando el resumen de información de grupos
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/sdc4 está en uso.
e2fsck: No se puede continuar, se finaliza.


e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/sdc3 está en uso.
e2fsck: No se puede continuar, se finaliza.

Paso 1: Verificando nodos-i, bloques y tamaños
Paso 1: Verificando nodos-i, bloques y tamaños
Paso 1: Verificando nodos-i, bloques y tamaños
Paso 1: Verificando nodos-i, bloques y tamaños
Paso 2: Verificando la estructura de directorios
Paso 1: Verificando nodos-i, bloques y tamaños
Tactinu1-Inicio: 11/133824 ficheros (0.0% no contiguos), 9196/535296 bloques
Paso 3: Revisando la conectividad de directorios
Paso 4: Revisando las cuentas de referencia
Paso 5: Revisando el resumen de información de grupos
Tactinu1-Slack64: 1450/1966560 ficheros (49.7% no contiguos), 5377699/7865600 bloques
Paso 2: Verificando la estructura de directorios
Paso 3: Revisando la conectividad de directorios
Paso 4: Revisando las cuentas de referencia
Paso 5: Revisando el resumen de información de grupos
Tactinu1-Slack32: 27765/1966080 ficheros (10.0% no contiguos), 5993183/7863808 bloques
Paso 2: Verificando la estructura de directorios
Paso 3: Revisando la conectividad de directorios
Paso 4: Revisando las cuentas de referencia
Paso 5: Revisando el resumen de información de grupos
Tactinu1: 81725/5709824 ficheros (25.0% no contiguos), 20667299/22807552 bloques
```

Desire output : First the echo output "Examinando : $Etiqueta ($Particion)", after fsck normal output "Paso 1" :

```
Examinando : 1SlackIni (/dev/sda1) 
Paso 1: Verificando nodos-i, bloques y tamaños
Paso 2: Verificando la estructura de directorios
Paso 3: Revisando la conectividad de directorios
Paso 4: Revisando las cuentas de referencia
Paso 5: Revisando el resumen de información de grupos
1SlackIni: 977/65536 ficheros (24.8% no contiguos), 114672/262144 bloques
```

[ wait for the before fsck finish ]

```
Examinando : 1SlackIni (/dev/sda1) 
Paso 1: Verificando nodos-i, bloques y tamaños
Paso 2: Verificando la estructura de directorios
Paso 3: Revisando la conectividad de directorios
Paso 4: Revisando las cuentas de referencia
Paso 5: Revisando el resumen de información de grupos
1SlackIni: 977/65536 ficheros (24.8% no contiguos), 114672/262144 bloques
```

[ Yes twice, because i ever do this two times ]

```
Examinando Compartido (/dev/sdb1)
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Paso 1: Verificando nodos-i, bloques y tamaños
Paso 2: Verificando la estructura de directorios
Paso 3: Revisando la conectividad de directorios
Paso 4: Revisando las cuentas de referencia
Paso 5: Revisando el resumen de información de grupos
Compartido: 1105544/39321600 ficheros (27.2% no contiguos), 149013032/157286400 bloques
```

The output is long.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, **never** parse the output of `ls` - that can never work reliably, there are far too many things that can (will!) cause it to fail.  Use `find ... -print0` and `mapfile` to populate an array instead.

e.g.

```bash
# Get all symlinks in /dev/disk/by-label/ except those
# containing Inukaze or LUBUNTU in the name.  Use NUL
# as the filename separator so it will work with ANY
# filename, even those containing annoying characters like
# spaces or shell metacharacters.
mapfile -d '' -t Etiqueta < <(
    find /dev/disk/by-label/ -type l \
    ! -name '*Inukaze*' \
    ! -name '*LUBUNTU*' \
    -print0)

# now loop over those symlinks
for f in "${Etiqueta[@]}" ; do
  # label name without path
  label="${f/*\//}"

  # get the real path of the symlink
  rp="$(realpath "$f")"

  # skip those that aren't block devices
  [ -b "$rp" ] || continue

  # skip block devs with size 72GB. Strip leading and
  # trailing spaces from lsblk's output with sed.
  size=$(lsblk -n -o size "$rp" | sed -E -e 's/^ *| *$//g') 
  [ "$size" = "72G" ] && continue 

  # Now do whatever you need to with "$rp".
  # Remember to always double-quote your variable expansions.

  # Use printf rather than echo because echo is unreliable and
  # easily broken.
  printf "\nExaminando: %s (%s)\n" "$label" "$rp"

  if fsck -fy "$rp" ; then
     if ! fsck -fy "$rp" ; then
       printf "%s\n" "Error second fsck of $label ($rp) failed." >&2
     fi
  else
    printf "%s\n" "Error: first fsck of $label ($rp) failed." >&2
  fi
done
```

See also:

- [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)
- run `help mapfile` in bash for more details on the mapfile built-in. https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/mapfile is also worth reading.

Comment: you probably want to skip `swap` partitions (and maybe other block dev types, e.g. `zfs_member` and maybe `linux_raid_member`) too.  You can get the fstype of a block dev with `fs=$(lsblk -n -o fstype "$f")`.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer, i don't know the existence of mapfile until you mention it. right now the mapfile version i am using, don't had the option "-d", what do that in your current distro ? in the link you put, neither have the "-d" option. if i delete "-d" the output result from mapfile is "mapfile: empty array variable name"

Comment: Well after some edits, is working, but what is best method from remove the output "Examinando: /dev/disk/by-label/Slack64 (/dev/sdb5)" the part "/dev/disk/by-label/" ?

Comment: 1. `mapfile` is a bash built-in, not an external program. It doesn't have a version (or, if you want, it has the same version as whatever version of bash you're running). According to bash's changelog, `mapfile` has had a `-d` option since bash 4.4-alpha (late 2015).     2. To remove all but the last `/` from a string, you can use bash's parameter expansion features, e.g. `var=/dev/disk/by-label/Slack64; echo ${var/*\//}` will print just `Slack64`. See `man bash` and search for `Parameter Expansion`.